# Cheap alternative to a SG Standard

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

Is there a money friendly guitar similar to the SG Standard?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean more price friendly than the Gibson SG, then the [Epiphone SG](http://www.epiphone.com/default.asp?ProductID=27&CollectionID=16) is what you want. Although it is much cheaper, in my opinion they are still very high quality guitars.

If you really just want the SG shape, then there is the [SG Special Cherry](http://www.hwmusic.co.uk/product/epiphone_67614.aspx) that Epiphone do. I am afraid I cannot provide any information about how good/bad the guitar is, but it is very affordable. The sellers link is selling it at £119, which equals $190. You may have to pay a little more for overseas shipping, but it is still extremely cheap.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Epiphone has some decent stuff for the price. I've played cheap ones too mind you, so go play one before you purchase (the universal rule of guitar buying)

Comment: "199 bucks is very price fine". Um... that wasn't in dollars, it was in Pounds. I realigned the link to point to Epiphone's site for the guitar's description. For pricing check with any of the music distributors you go to normally as shipping from UK to US will eat up any possible savings.

Comment: My first electric was a 60's SG Standard, and I remember seeing where there was filler between the neck and body joint. 

Given today's use of CDC machines to cut the wood and the emphasis on quality in the factories making a lot of imported guitars, I wouldn't be surprised if Epiphone's SG isn't better than the original once you subtract the Gibson reputation and mystique.

Comment: For the sake of completion, right now £199 = $318. Good point Tin Man, do check local distributors. I have revised my answer to give another option if wished. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, you just posted your 2nd comment as I was writing my response! Sorry, forgive me but I don't understand the last part of your sentence: 'I wouldn't be surprised if Epiphone's SG isn't better than the original.' Does that mean you think that the Epi SG is not as good as the Gibson one? Sorry, I'm probably just being thick. Thanks :)

Comment: It means Epiphone's is probably better than Gibson's originals. The build quality on the original guitars was so-so compared to today's standards. I've had a bunch of Gibson and Fender guitars, and I'd put my Ibanez guitars up against them for build quality any day. Now, mystique and reputation? Gibson's got that over them.

Answer (score 0):

if by "similar" you mean "same shape" then ya, the Epiphone SG's are one option.

ESP's LTD line has a guitar called a Viper which has a simiular yet more aggressive shape than the SG. They go from ~ $200 - $1,000 depending one which model u pick. Here's a link to musiciansfriend to check em out along w/ their price http://bit.ly/ea471n

Another thing to consider is to buy a used SG. Gibson made a bunch of guiitars with a "faded finish" which were cheaper than their standard ones. So search ebay for Gibson SG Faded and you'll see a handful of guitars priced much lower than a new, standard SG. These go for $500 - $700 or so.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great brand which is called "vintage". They have licenced copies of SG, and it's so nice to play with it!! I know many people who changed pickups to gibson and doesn't want to buy original, Infact I have strat-mexico copy and I'm really not gonna buy original, because one of fender guys (working in fender, and they made workshop that day) said that my strato-mexico plays even better then his original guitar =))) So I think this kind of opinion really says something about this brand =)

So just [checkout](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-9SigjihPU&feature=player_embedded) what they have